# Unable to use Eclipse on Linux Unity

Tags: linux, eclipse, operating-system, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to install Eclipse, but it won't let me extract the files.

I have eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz open under "Network". Inside that I have an eclipse folder. I click on that and I'm unable to click eclipse, the icon is paper with binary on it(so is a bunch of other files.

Im on a chromebook and I've installed Linux Unity.

EDIT: Ive now been able to unzip the file. But now when I click the Eclipse.exe, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll need to actually unpack the tarball somewhere. You will not be able to run it otherwise.

Comment: You have Eclipse**.exe** on Linux??

Answer (score 0):

Unpack it with

```
tar xvzf eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

Then go to the eclipse-folder and start it with

```
./eclipse
```

from the shell. That should give you some information, if it's not successful.

Maybe you have to make it executable before. To do so type

```
chmod +x eclipse
```

If you have downloaded a linux version, there should be nothing like "eclipse.exe".